# Calculate the percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, average, where-clause, percentage

I need to find the Total # of Hires in a population.
Then I need to find the percentage of that population where gender is female.

I have tried :
-- the Total # of Hires in a population

```
select count(Hires) from Employees for the employees
```

-- percentage of the above population where gender is female.

```
select COUNT(Hires) from Employees
Where Gender='Female') * 100.0 / (select count (Hires) FROM employees
```

but it gives me a large percentage

Comment: I think you want (Females/Total) * 100.  Don't forget to cast the counts to decimals or you'll end up with integer division.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `avg()`:

```
select avg(case when gender = 'Female' then 100.0 else 0 end) as percent_female
from employees
where hires is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need percentage for all values in the Gender column.

```
select Gender, count(*) * 100.00/ (select count(*) from Employees)
from Employees
group by Gender
```